# OFFSET/LIMIT only count DISTINCT values in Activerecord query

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, limit, distinct, offset

I am running this query

```
Playlistship.order("created_at desc").select("distinct playlist_id").limit(12).offset(2)
```

This query does not necessarily return 12 records. It returns the number of distinct records in the set of 12 defined by the `LIMIT`, `OFFSET` and `ORDER` parameters.

For example if the `Playlistships` between `id`=13 and `id`=24 had `playlist_ids` of [2,3,3,5,6,3,5,6,8,11,12,12], then this query will only give return 7 records, corresponding to the first ones having the `playlist_ids` [2,3,5,6,8,11,12].

What I would like to find is a query that yields 12, records with distinct `playlist_ids`, with the correct offset so that running this query again with an `OFFSET` of 3 would yield the next 12 records with distinct `playlist_ids`.

Hopefully I didn't "over explain" this one, as I think it's a relatively straightforward question. Please ask for more details if you need them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with subqueries? Give this a try:

```
Playlistship.select("distinct playlist_id").limit(12).where(playlist_id: Playlistship.order("created_at desc").select('playlist_id').offset(2))
```